# How does Facebook searches for groups?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I want to search Facebook's large collection of groups from the Graph API using the 'q' parameter, but I get the feeling I can only search by the group's **name** and not by other fields such as the group's 'Description' field or any other classification.

Am I wrong? Does Facebook internal search  already searches within the description or classifies the groups somehow?

Thank you!